# is it possible to convert PDF to Word using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, ms-word

I am looking for a way of processing PDFs and outputting a .doc, while retaining as much formatting as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use the shell from your app? The way I usually handle it is by using an existing linux program and just call that from Rails. I'm not familiar with any gem that does it "internally".

Comment: Do you have to start with PDF?  If your system is creating the PDF, then perhaps it's better to go XX -> PDF | DOC.  I don't know anything that can give you a decent derivative of a PDF, but there are things that can produce PDF and DOC.

Comment: @PeterDuijnstee how you do it ? Which utility you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use openoffice in headless mode and [unoconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unoconv) is shell utility or [pdftotext](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext).
Or you can use [jodconvereter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter),i have written small ruby wrapper [convert_office](https://github.com/amardaxini/convert_office/),
Just checkit out supported format,jodconverter is a java library which requires openoffice.